# How to nest two websites in the same nginx server block

Tags: nginx

With nginx, I'm trying to setup two static websites on the same domain. The first being at `example.com`, and the other being a small React app at `example.com/haiku`. How can this be done?

I'm running into issues where the stylesheet and javascript files for `example.com/haiku` are being requested from the main `example.com`. As all page resource URIs start with a slash (ex `/static/style.css`), nginx is processing them as belonging to `example.com` rather than getting them from `/haiku`.

Both websites occupy separate directories on the server. `example.com` is at `/srv/http/domain`, and `example.com/haiku` is at `/srv/http/haiku`

Here's the pertinent part of my nginx's server block:

```
root /srv/http;
location / {
  root /srv/http/domain;
}
location /haiku {
  alias /srv/http/haiku;
}
```

I've done my research on these nginx modules, and I understand why this isn't working right now. Navigating to `example.com/haiku/index.html` serves the page, but its references to `/static/css/style.css` and `/static/js/main.js` are hitting the `/` location block. I need some kind of internal rewrite that will take `/static/css/style.css` and change it to `/haiku/static/css/style.css`, where the file is located. I'm not finding similar questions on Google or SE.

I know that I can easily solve this by getting another domain. I know I can also setup a sub-domain, but I specifically want to know if this can be done by nesting one static website in the request of another website with no DNS configuration needed.

I also don't want to just change the URIs for the css and js files, because I want to be able to deploy this little React app on any server-block root.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to facilitate this is to configure the root URL of the application so that it generates correct resource URLs in the first place.

https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/ shows one approach for React to configure application base URL.

It is not a good idea to do any rewriting of HTML on nginx side. It will consume extra resources and it can cause undesired side-effects.

Comment: Yes, changing the root URL of the app was the solution for my problem. Create React App's documentation on changing the root URL was also valuable to me:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths